# linux text editor for windows

Tags: windows, linux, text-editors, tcsh, csh

can somebody recommend a good Linux text editor for Windows (if it exists), I wrote scripts for C-Shell using txt editor of windows but I have problem, it doesn't run because windows is not UNIX, what can I do? I don't want to install linux for a few scripts, I do testing of my scripts via unix server (this server is not mine), thanks in advance, also I treed `dos2unix command`, also doesn't work

Comment: What happens when you run `dos2unix`? Error message? What happens when you run a script that's been processed by `dos2unix`? If you're trying to run your script in Windows `cmd.exe`, then you're right "Windows is not Unix". You will need to install Cygwin as **Henno** suggests or install Linux, or get access to a Linux or Unix system. And if you can, use any other shell besides csh or tcsh.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you aren't able to *run* the scripts. The editor you're using won't matter. You can use Windows Notepad or Notepad++ or any other. What you need to find is a c-shell which runs under Windows for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[vim](http://www.vim.org)' has a windows port [over there](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/downloads/list). and you can save files with unix-lineending (among a lot of other things).

Answer (score 6):

I like using [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). It has an EOL (end of line) converter under Edit...EOL ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889163/eol-in-notepad-and-notepad)).

Answer (score 3):

You could try and install Cygwin, this will give you a relatively complete Linux environment within Windows. You can configure it to install just what you need (like a shell and a few utilities, and vi or emacs), and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Windows GUI app for text editing in a format that is Linux friendly, [EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com) is a good tool.

Comment: Probably not the answer the poster is looking for, since dos2unix didnt help either.

Answer (score 0):

What does the file look look when you look at it in a plaint text editor such as notepad?

If it looks sensible as a text file in Windows, then you could try using the Windows (command line) version of [dos2unix](http://www.bastet.com/), although I would be surprised if the dos2unix program had a problem.

Look at it again to see that only the line breaks have changed.

What happens when you look at the file on the server? Does it look sensible?

Are you sure that the script works? (Have you remembered to make the script executable?)